# Updating in the index - YII2

Tags: yii2

I created a CRUD for one of my tables. I want the ability to update one of the columns in the index. I want to have an option of a dropdown , in the cell in the index, for choosing a different value for the attribute. My goal is to enable updating multiple rows, in a quick way. Is it possible? 
thank you.

Comment: you just check your table in database

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of Kartik's [Form Builders](http://demos.krajee.com/builder), more specifically his [Tabular Form Widget](http://demos.krajee.com/builder-details/tabular-form)

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying to use Kartik's extention, but i get this error: 'Class 'kartik\editable\Editable' not found'. I installed it via the composer. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try reinstalling it. Delete `"kartik-v/yii2-builder": "@dev",` from your `composer.json` file, then do a composer update and finally install it again running `php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-builder "@dev"`

Comment: A few other things. Make sure you setup the gridview module. Make sure the `kartik-v/yii2-widgets` extension is installed inside the vendor directory.

Comment: Setup the gridview module in the config? I did that.. kartik-v/yii2-widgets is in the vendor. Any else ideas..? Thanks..